# Sencha cmd - Grid Rowediting

Tags: extjs, grid

I have a grid, when I open it the first time I can edit normal use the RowEditing plugin. When I close the window to edit and open again I can not edit.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use for cancel event and if you want to update then use update on the place of "canceledit"

```
var rowEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
    clicksToMoveEditor: 1,
    //autoCancel: false,
    listeners:{
        'canceledit': function(rowEditing, context) {
            // Canceling editing of a locally added, unsaved record: remove it
            if (context.record.phantom) {
                context.store.remove(context.record);
            }
        }
    }
});
```